# Replace pandas values in a column by a look up from a different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a reference DataFrame like below:

```
    Variables   Key Values  
0   GRTYPE      40  Total exclusions 4-year schools
1   GRTYPE      2   4-year institutions, Adjusted cohort
2   GRTYPE      3   4-year institutions, Completers 
41  CHRTSTAT    2   Revised cohort
42  CHRTSTAT    3   Exclusions
43  CHRTSTAT    4   Adjusted cohort 
57  SECTION     12  Bachelors/ equiv .
58  SECTION     23  Bachelors or equiv 2009 .
```

and I would like to use the reference data frame to replace the values in the main DataFrame below:

```
    GRTYPE      CHRTSTAT  SECTION
0   40             2    12      
1   2              3    12      
2   2              4    23      
3   3              2    12  
4   3              3    23
```

The end result would be:

```
    GRTYPE                                CHRTSTAT          SECTION
0   Total exclusions 4-year schools         Revised cohort       Bachelors/ equiv . 
1   4-year institutions, Adjusted cohort    Exclusions           Bachelors/ equiv .         
2   4-year institutions, Adjusted cohort    Adjusted cohort      Bachelors or equiv 2009 .      
3   4-year institutions, Completers         Revised cohort       Bachelors/ equiv . 
4   4-year institutions, Completers         Exclusions           Bachelors or equiv 2009 .
```

What is the best way of doing this in pandas or python? I tried joining and extracting the variables from the first dataframe and loop over the second one and did not get anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Using `map`

You need to set `Variables` and `Key` as indexes of the mapping dataframe and then simply use **[map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html)** on columns.

```
mapping_df = mapping_df.set_index(['Variables', 'Key'])
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.map(mapping_df.loc[x.name]['Values']))
```

Which is same as:

```
mapping_df = mapping_df.set_index(['Variables', 'Key'])
df['GRTYPE'] = df.GRTYPE.map(mapping_df.loc['GRTYPE']['Values'])
df['CHRTSTAT'] = df.CHRTSTAT.map(mapping_df.loc['CHRTSTAT']['Values'])
df['SECTION'] = df.SECTION.map(mapping_df.loc['SECTION']['Values'])
```

Output:

```
                                 GRTYPE         CHRTSTAT                    SECTION
0       Total exclusions 4-year schools   Revised cohort         Bachelors/ equiv .
1  4-year institutions, Adjusted cohort       Exclusions         Bachelors/ equiv .
2  4-year institutions, Adjusted cohort  Adjusted cohort  Bachelors or equiv 2009 .
3       4-year institutions, Completers   Revised cohort         Bachelors/ equiv .
4       4-year institutions, Completers       Exclusions  Bachelors or equiv 2009 .
```

Comment: Excellent thanks. I had a little issue since the result were not showing up and that was due to the type of column must be converted to string from the number to accept strings.

Answer (score 2):

### Using a `defualtdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)
for i, k, v in df1.itertuples(index=False):
    d[i][k] = v

pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(df2, [[d[i][k] for k in df2[i]] for i in df2])), df2.index)

                                 GRTYPE         CHRTSTAT                    SECTION
0       Total exclusions 4-year schools   Revised cohort         Bachelors/ equiv .
1  4-year institutions, Adjusted cohort       Exclusions         Bachelors/ equiv .
2  4-year institutions, Adjusted cohort  Adjusted cohort  Bachelors or equiv 2009 .
3       4-year institutions, Completers   Revised cohort         Bachelors/ equiv .
4       4-year institutions, Completers       Exclusions  Bachelors or equiv 2009 .
```

---

### `apply`

```
df2.apply(
    lambda s: s.apply(
        lambda x, n: df1.set_index(['Variables', 'Key']).Values[(n, x)], n=s.name
    )
)

                                 GRTYPE         CHRTSTAT                    SECTION
0       Total exclusions 4-year schools   Revised cohort         Bachelors/ equiv .
1  4-year institutions, Adjusted cohort       Exclusions         Bachelors/ equiv .
2  4-year institutions, Adjusted cohort  Adjusted cohort  Bachelors or equiv 2009 .
3       4-year institutions, Completers   Revised cohort         Bachelors/ equiv .
4       4-year institutions, Completers       Exclusions  Bachelors or equiv 2009 .
```